# How do I get nested json values from parsed JSON?

Tags: python, json

I'm new to python and having issues getting data from a JSON response to make a new request.

I am able to get the response, which looks like this after I convert the xml response to json:

```
{
  "Response": {
    "Total": "9",
    "ReportIP": "64.60.199.26",
    "Orders": {
      "Order": [
        {
          "Id": "831186",
          "Items": {
            "Item": {
              "ItemID": "64021"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "Id": "831748",
          "Items": {
            "Item": [
              {
                "ItemID": "64017"
              },
              {
                "ItemID": "64018"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
orders = parsedData["Response"]['Orders']["Order"]

for order in orders:
    print(order["Id"])
    print(order["Items"]["Item"].get("ItemID"))
```

My goal is to get the Order["Id"] and the associated Item"ID", but I run into an issue when and order has multiple items:

```
831186
64021
831748
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wsm-lineitems.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(order["Items"]["Item"].get("ItemID"))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: @martineau Scroll down

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: the first occurrence of an object with key `Item` is an object, while the second one is an array that you would have to traverse through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best if you used consistent format of the data. If there can be multiple items, then `Item` should always contain a list, even if it's just a single element.

But if you're stuck with this format, you have to check whether the value is a single item or a list. You can replace the single item with a list and then iterate over it.

```
for order in orders:
    print(order["Id"])
    order_items = order['Items']['Item']
    if not isinstance(order_items, list):
        order_items = [order_items] # wrap a single item into a list.
    for item in order_items:
        print(item.get("ItemID"))
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I dont have access to the data to change the format :(